# Uses for TR-31 Key Version Number?

Tags: key-management, key-generation

The standard for TR-31 (and Thales) Key blocks ([ref](https://www.eftlab.com/tr31-and-thales-key-blocks/)) have a field for "Key Version Number", which is only defined in the spec as

> Two-digit ASCII character version number,
> optionally used to indicate that contents of the
> key block is a component, or to prevent reinjection of old keys.

Using it as a way to indicate a key component makes sense to me, but I'm struggling to understand under what circumstances this field would be useful as a *version* number.  Why would someone version a key instead of just creating a new one - is there any practical difference between the two?  What security or key management benefits can versioning provide?

Or is it more to be treated similarly to the optional blocks, where any given implementation could use it for whatever purpose it finds useful regardless of whether that has anything to do with versioning?

Answer (score -1):

you can calculate TR-31 key block online. https://www.kabc.ca/keys/tr31

Comment: That's a really useful link, but it doesn't answer my question at all.  I know how to parse a TR-31 block (although this looks like a more convenient tool), but it still just says "Version Number" for that field, with no explaination.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).